# jquery scrolling on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, scroll

I have some jquery that nicely scrolls from a top div to a bottom div.  To prevent the target div flashing momentarily on click I included  an event.preventDefault.

This works great on Chrome and IE but not Firefox.  When I remove the preventDefault it works on Firefox too but the flash is back.

I'm not great at javascript or jquery but is there a way to prevent the flash without using preventDefault or a way to get preventDefault to work in Firefox?

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nextPage").click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#secondContainer").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
        $("#prevPage").click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#firstContainer").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

```css
#firstContainer {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: green;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
      }
      
      #secondContainer {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: blue;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
      }
      
      #nextPage {
        position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 2%;
        transform:translateX(-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -o-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
        background: white;
        color: blue;
      }
      
      #prevPage {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 2%;
        transform:translateX(-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -o-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
        background: white;
        color: green;
      }
```

```html
<div id="firstContainer">
    <a id="nextPage" href="#secondContainer">Next</a>
</div> <!-- closes #firstContainer -->
  
<div id="secondContainer">
    <a id="prevPage" href="#firstContainer">Previous</a>
</div> <!-- closes #secondContainer -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**
You could remove the `event.preventDefault();` and make the function `return false`.

eg:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nextPage").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#secondContainer").offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
        $("#prevPage").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#firstContainer").offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
  });
```

**Option 2**
You could use a span tag instead (removing the href attribute ofcourse)

**Option 3**
Just remove the href attribute from the anchor (this wont be valid html though)

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/a19brozb/) is a fiddle with the return false option.